# Window from nib in dylib

Tags: cocoa, window, macos-carbon, nib, dylib

I'm quite new to the Mac but reasonably expirienced with windows.
What I need is a window owned opened and closed by the library (dylib).
This is very easy to do in MS Windows but seems not be hard under Cocoa.

I used the code from apple's 'CocoaInCarbon' example with C++ Wrappers.
But the `NSApplicationLoad()` followed by `[NSBundle LoadNibNamed:@"MyWindow" owner:self]` fails. Is this caused by the dylib not being a bundle.

Are there alternative ways to open and control a window within a dylib?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the problem is that it's not a bundle; your nib can't possibly be inside a bundle that doesn't exist, so how would the code find it to open it?

You need to either use a framework (which is a bundle), and ship the nib in that framework, or you need to create the entire window programmatically in your dylib.

Comment: Ok, thank you, I get it.  Are you aware of samplecode illustrating solution A and or B?

Jan

Answer (score 0):

It's not a standard practice to just ship `dylib` on Mac, when the shared library is not very low level and involves GUI in particular. You package it into a `framework`, so that it can not only have codes in it, but associated resources (nibs, images, sounds) in one place.

Read [this Apple document](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPFrameworks/Frameworks.html) to understand what's going on and how to prepare it. Or, take a look at `/System/Library/Frameworks/` to see how the OS X itself provides libraries.